# Power BI Drill Through Small Multiples

Tags: powerbi, drillthrough

I have created Small Multiples Bar Chart based on Year and Category.

I have a detail report where I set Drill Through field as Year.

So when I right click any bar in Small Multiples to see the details, it shows me to drill through. All good till now.

**Requirement**: I need to allow drill through from only one category of small multiples. So drill through should appear on only that chart which has category value say XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. The closest to achieve this is via a [conditional Drillthrough button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drill-through-buttons) (see section "Set the drillthrough destination conditionally"). This won't stop the right-click drillthrough though.